# Why might a DynamoDB scan fail to paginate properly?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB, and although there is a DAX cluster associated with this database, I am looking to do some scans just on the underlying database for now. (I am running this code locally with session-based AWS auth, and DynamoDB is available in the default VPC, but DAX appears to be in a private VPC, so I can't reach that for now. I will treat that as a separate problem).

I want to run a scan that gets all records. There are about 4k rows in the table, and I am only getting about 1.2K rows, which I put down to DynamoDB's design, which can only serve 1M per page. So I have created a loop, but it seems to be looping in the pagination, and going back to the start.

Here is some code:

```
interface CreditKey {
  emailAddress: string;
  shopperGroupId: number;
}

const options = {
  endpoint: 'http://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
};
const dynamoDbServiceClient = new DynamoDB(options);
const dynamoDbDocumentClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient(options);

let nextPage: DynamoDB.Key | undefined;
let rows: CreditKey[] = [];
let page: DocumentClient.ScanOutput;

console.log(`** Start`);
// Ooh, so DynamoDB won't serve more than 1MB per scan, so we if want
// the lot, we have to keep asking for it in pages! 
do {
  page = await docClient
    .scan({
      TableName: tableName,
      Limit: 1000,
      ExclusiveStartKey: nextPage,
    })
    .promise();
  rows = rows.concat(<CreditKey[]> page.Items);
  nextPage = page.LastEvaluatedKey;
  if (nextPage) {
    console.log(`DynamoDB is paginating...`);
    console.log(nextPage);
    console.log((<CreditKey[]> page.Items).length);
  }
} while (nextPage !== null);
console.log(`** End`);
```

Here is the output:

```
root@81323cd19efa:/project# USER_CREDIT_TABLE_NAME=user-credits-preprod ts-node scripts/credits/find-duplicate-credits.ts
Table: user-credits-preprod
Found table primary keys: emailAddress, shopperGroupId
** Start
DynamoDB is paginating...
{
  emailAddress: 'support+adminportal+1906912@example.com',
  shopperGroupId: '1'
}
1000
DynamoDB is paginating...
{
  emailAddress: 'support+adminportal+518180@example.com',
  shopperGroupId: '2'
}
1000
DynamoDB is paginating...
{
  emailAddress: 'support+adminportal+1906085@example.com',
  shopperGroupId: '17'
}
1000
DynamoDB is paginating...
{
  emailAddress: 'support+adminportal+1906866@example.com',
  shopperGroupId: '39'
}
1000
DynamoDB is paginating...
{
  emailAddress: 'support+adminportal+1906912@example.com',
  shopperGroupId: '1'
}
1000
```

So we can see that the last composite/primary key is the same as the first one, which indicates that the scan has looped around and started again. But it look like `ExclusiveStartKey` / `LastEvaluatedKey` *is* producing a variety of keys, so it is partly working. In other words, this is getting stuck in a loop (and it does not get to the `** End`). This doesn't seem to make much sense - I can't imagine why this would be an expected behaviour.

I don't know DynamoDB well. I wonder what I can try next - maybe a Query instead of a Scan? It does not have to be performant.

### Update

I am starting to try Query, and currently it says:

> Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request

I can probably find an expression that includes all records, but I'd rather get Scan working if I can - it feels like it should work.

### Update 2

A good point is raised in the comments - the AWS SDK version. `^2.828.0` is requested in the `package.json`, and it looks like the lock file is specifying `3.29.0` for most `@aws-sdk/*` items, with occasional items going to `3.30.0`.

The dependency constraints are in a bit of a mess in this project, and I am trying to install the AWS JS SDK separately for this script.

### Update 3

I am sensibly advised to try `aws dynamodb scan` on the console. Responses contain `LastEvaluatedKey` as one would expect, and `--exclusive-start-key` can be added to the console. This seems to work for me - I supply the LEK output as the ESK input until no LEK is returned (in the last page).

For example the second call looks like this:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name user-credits-preprod --limit 1000 --last-evaluated-key='{
    "emailAddress": {
        "S": "support+adminportal+1906912@example.com"
    },
    "shopperGroupId": {
        "S": "1"
    }
}'
```

This approach produces the following pattern.

LEK 1:

```
{
    "emailAddress": {
        "S": "support+adminportal+1906912@example.com"
    },
    "shopperGroupId": {
        "S": "1"
    }
}
```

LEK 2:

```
{
    "emailAddress": {
        "S": "support+adminportal+518180@example.com"
    },
    "shopperGroupId": {
        "S": "2"
    }
}
```

LEK 3:

```
{
    "emailAddress": {
        "S": "support+adminportal+1906085@example.com"
    },
    "shopperGroupId": {
        "S": "17"
    }
}
```

LEK 4:

```
{
    "emailAddress": {
        "S": "support+adminportal+1906866@example.com"
    },
    "shopperGroupId": {
        "S": "39"
    }
}
```

LEK 5: none

Each blob has 1000 records, except the last one, which has 67 - success! So now I need to see if I can convert this back to the SDK call.

(Aside: I note that `--last-evaluated-key` is not in `aws dynamodb scan help`).

Comment: Be sure that you are using the current AWS JavaScript SDK. Test with the awscli (`aws dynamodb scan`) to see if it works correctly. On the frustration related to having to paginate, how would you implement a function like this that supports 20 items, 20k items, 20 million items and more, without pagination?

Comment: @jarmod: I suppose I'd like scan to return as many record as it can, and fails if I run out of local memory. This would force people to put in a Limit and paginate. In my case this is for a one-off repair script of prod data, so I can make a judgement about whether it will run on a production dataset (and with 10K it should be fine).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to look at the version of the AWS SDK - will check that next.

Comment: The CLI includes a tokenized abstraction of the pagination key/token but both the awscli scan and your JavaScript SDK scan call result in the same underlying [scan API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html). The point about testing with awscli scan is simply to check that it returns the correct items (at least beyond the point that your JavaScript SDK scan call seems to fail).

Comment: Ah, I have an update - will amend. No solution yet, but pagination does work in the cli.

Comment: I am voting to close as "typo/unrepro" on my own question here - it probably isn't useful to readers, since the cause was not Dynamo.

Comment: Ha ha, closure failed here and my vote aged away. So I tried to delete it, skipped through the terrible consequences dialogue box, and the system rejected my request anyway 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with typescript, but my guess is that the exit condition from the loop doesn't work: On the **last** page, the LastEvaluatedKey would be missing, but perhaps it's not `null` as your loop test checks but something else (`undefined`?). If the loop continues with `nextPage=undefined`, it basically restarts, which is what you see.

Moreover, the fact that the printout only shows pages of 1000 results, not the last one (which would have less than 1000 results), suggests that the `if (nextPage) {` does work as expected, it's just that `} while (nextPage !== null);` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I just had a breakthrough Nadav, thank you - went right around the houses! You are quite right, this was at least part of the solution. It may be the full solution, although I have been tinkering with `apiVersion` and upgrading the SDK from 2.x to 3.x as well. I now have to unwrap my stack of messy changes to narrow it down 

Comment: I think almost everything mentioned in this question and comments - dax, SDK versions, etc., are just red herrings that are not related to the real bug you had in your code. I'm guessing if you just fix the loop condition, it will work for any SDK version. Scanning is a very basic operation, which probably worked correctly in version 1.0 of the SDK.

Comment: Quite right, I appreciate your help - a line of herrings as long as your arm!  I should have been dumping the `page` object to see what the termination condition should have been.